# Incompatibile types: List<A> cannot be converted to List<U>

Tags: java, generics

Could someone explain to me why this piece of code does not compile? When I replace `U` with `?` it works. Why it is not inferred to be `Object`?

```
class Scratch {
    static <U> List<U> method(int x) {
        if (x < 50) {
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<Number>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not matter how he calls it, this is never going to work. `String` is not a `U` and `Number` is not a `U`, that is fundamentally not how generics work.

Comment: `List<String> strings = Scratch.method(999);` - **booom** (when inserting and reading from the list afterwards). The compiler forbids this.

Comment: Generics are compile-time type checking. The *compiler* needs to be able to make the inference. You are doing a runtime boolean evaluation which does not make sense. At runtime, regardless of the value of X, the thing which is going to be returned is just an `ArrayList` with no specific type. i.e. both paths of the if-statement are identical.

Comment: How are you expecting to use that method? What is the type of the variable you want to assign the result to, how do you plan on inserting anything into the list?

Comment: A "better" usage would be with `static <T> List<T> buildList(Class<T> c)` allowing to use it like `List<String> l = buildList(String.class);`

Comment: @AxelH why would you use that instead of `new ArrayList<>()`?

Comment: @AxelH There is already a method like that. It's called a constructor, and you don't have to specify the class twice.

Comment: A `List<Number>` is **not** a `List<Object>`, because **generics are invariant.** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/2745301#2745301) explains why.

Comment: @Michael I said "better" for a reason ;) the code propose kept his "requirements"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `ArrayList<Object>` and say `ArrayList<String>` are not related types that is `ArrayList<String>` does not inherit from `ArrayList<Object>` and can't be converted to it.

If for a second we imagine this can be done this code will be not type safe:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = ...;

ArrayList<Object> objectList = stringList; // this is what is not allowed in reality

objectList.add(new Integer());
```

Now you have integer in `stringList` which is definitely what you do not expect to have in type safe program.

Comment: I've seen this example dozen of times and still forgot about it :)

Comment: While this is true it does not really relate to the question. The invariance of generics is not what's causing the problems here. The problem is that `U` is inferred from the caller and there is no guarantee that the `U` a caller expects has anything to do with the type of the list returned. The problem is as I stated in my first comment: `String` is not a `U`. If the method would be `static <U> List<U> method() { return new ArrayList<String>();` it would still not work for that reason.